# XSL for transformation of text node

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, element, transformation

There is a xml (for the example the xml is simplified)

```
<object attr1="1" attr2="2">
xxxxxxxxx
  <someattrs>
    <someattr1>a</someattr1>
    <someattr2>b</someattr2>
    <someattr3>c</someattr3>
    <someattr4 attr3="3">
       yyyyyyy
       <someattr5>d</someattr5>
       <someattr6>e</someattr6>
       <someattr7 attr8="f">
         <![CDATA[ zzzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz  ]]> 
       </someattr7>
    </someattr4>
  </someattrs>
</object>
```

With the xls transformation **which is meant to transform any xml that has attributes into element-centric xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the xml transforms to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object>
   <attr1>1</attr1>
   <attr2>2</attr2>
   xxxxxxxxx
   <someattrs>
      <someattr1>a</someattr1>
      <someattr2>b</someattr2>
      <someattr3>c</someattr3>
      <someattr4>
         <attr3>3</attr3>
         yyyyyyy
         <someattr5>d</someattr5>
         <someattr6>e</someattr6>
         <someattr7>
            <attr8>f</attr8>
            zzzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz
         </someattr7>
      </someattr4>
   </someattrs>
</object>
```

The problem is that any free text() that appears in the source xml didn't go in it's own tag (let's put all free texts to elements with names "sometext") in the final xml. The text "xxxxxxxxx" should go in its own tag `<sometext>xxxxxxxxx</sometext>` and "yyyyyyy" should go in its own tag `<sometext>yyyyyyy</sometext>`.

**What is the transformation to get the following xml?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object>
   <attr1>1</attr1>
   <attr2>2</attr2>
   <sometext>xxxxxxxxx</sometext>
   <someattrs>
      <someattr1>a</someattr1>
      <someattr2>b</someattr2>
      <someattr3>c</someattr3>
      <someattr4>
         <attr3>3</attr3>
         <sometext>yyyyyyy</sometext>
         <someattr5>d</someattr5>
         <someattr6>e</someattr6>
         <someattr7>
            <attr8>f</attr8>
            <sometext>zzzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz</sometext>
         </someattr7>
      </someattr4>
   </someattrs>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of formatting-only text nodes:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Create `<sometext>` elements from text-only nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="object/text()">
    <sometext><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></sometext>
</xsl:template>
```

---

UPDATE

General solution for any element:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*|@*]/text()">
    <sometext><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></sometext>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ty for the strip-space. :) The xsl cannot use "object" in match since source xml contains texts not only in object node :(. `<xsl:template match="text()"><sometext><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></sometext></xsl:template>` without "object" gives: `....<someattr1><sometext>a</sometext></someattr1><someattr2><sometext>b</sometext></someattr2>...` which is excessive since it should be `<someattr1>a</someattr1><someattr2>b</someattr2>`.

Comment: How to distinguish texts that have to be enclosed in `<sometext>` from texts that don't have to?

Comment: If the element has "text" and child elements,then the text should appear as element "<sometext>text</sometext>.The <object> has has a text ("xxxxxxxxx") and element <someattrs>..., that way the text after transformation should appear in <sometext>xxxxxxxxx</sometext>; <someattr4 attr3="3"> has text ("yyyyyyy") and child elements <someattr5>, <someattr6>, <someattr7>..., that way the text after transformation should appear in <sometext>yyyyyyy<sometext>. In contrary <someattr1>a</someattr1> has no child elements so it's text ("a") should not appear in sometext. Idk how to do distinguish them.:)

Comment: For the xml `<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<A attr1="111" attr2="222">
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  <B>
    <C attr3="111">yyy</C> 
    <D>dddddddddddddd</D> 
    <E attr4="111">
        zzzzzzzzzzzzz
      <F>ffffffffff</F> 
      <G>ggggggggg</G> 
      <H>hhhhhhhhhhhh</H> 
    </E>
  </B>
</A>` the match `<xsl:template match="*[*]/text()">
    <sometext><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></sometext>
</xsl:template>` produced `<A>
... <sometext>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</sometext>
....
      <C>
         <attr3>111</attr3>
         yyy
      </C>
    ...`  yyy didn't appear in sometext. :/

Comment: Here is what I do and what I get  https://gist.github.com/spookiecookie/917133428d46509dfe9b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79093/discussion-between-dlask-and-marius-zilnas).

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@*]/text()">
        <sometext><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></sometext>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: ty:). how come `*[@*]` and are the same `*[*|@*]` i.e. give the same result?

Comment: it means `*[*]` or `*[@*]`

Comment: I tested both on a large xml and it gives identical results :).